# File download from API with it's name in 'content-disposition' in Angular

Tags: angular, api, download, get, content-disposition

Hi i have downloaded the file from API as mentioned below:

This downloads the file successfully.But i want to download the file with the name they have attached from API in content-disposition as below :
[image]

- shop-detail.component.ts file :

```
  onDownloadWhitePaper(): void {
    if( this.isValidUser()){
      this.downloadFile("white_paper");
        }
    }

  onDownloadDataSheet(): void {
    if (this.isValidUser()) {
      this.downloadFile("data_sheet")
    }
  }

 
  private downloadFile(type:string): void {
      const categoryId = this.productDetail.category_id;
      this.shopService.downloadWhitePaper(categoryId,type)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.blob = new Blob(
          [res], 
          { type :'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}
          );
        var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadURL;
        link.download = "sample.docx"
        link.click();
        
      });
  }
```

- I have called the API as below in service :
- shop.service.ts :

```
  downloadWhitePaper(id:number,type:string): any {
    const options = {
      responseType:'blob' as 'json',
    }
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(
      `${this.apiUrl}/v1/sheets/downloads?category_id=${id}&type=${type}`,
        options
    );
  }
```

So please help to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `HttpClient` to include it by setting up `observe` option.

Try this:

```
const options = {
  responseType:'blob' as 'json',
  observe: 'response'
}
```

and then you read it:

```
res.headers.get('content-disposition')
```

and then you'll need to extract it somehow, for example:

```
res.headers.get('content-disposition')?.split('filename=')[1].split(';')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry, I forgot to update my question. I have died the issue